# Wi-fi turns on when I boot my phone

Tags: wi-fi, samsung, boot

For the past few days the wi-fi on my phone has been automatically turning on whenever I boot up my phone (Samsung Galaxy Light, SGH-T399) when it's fully turned off or restarted. To address the last time someone asked, I have tried turning on wi-fi then restarting my phone, and it still loads with wi-fi turned on. I also don't have any automation apps installed. I have only installed one new app recently, about a week before this started (GroupMe), I have any wi-fi settings turned off for the app, and the issue continues with the app uninstalled.

Is there a way to keep my phone from turning on wi-fi when it boots?

Comment: This seem to be a typical Samsung crap-ware issue. Are you sure it even worked before? Perhaps you never really noticed it before.